# Chain assigning columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a strange problem with SQLAlchemy that happen only infrequently.

I have two mapped classes:

```
class cQuantum(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mesQuantum'
    quanID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    quantityTransferred = Column(Float)
    quantityActual = Column(Float)
    received = Column(DateTime)

class cTransfer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mesTransfer'
    transferID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    quanID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ForeignKey('mesQuantum.quanID'))
    quantityTransferred = Column(Float)
    quantityActual = Column(Float)
    finished = Column(DateTime)
    quanObj = relationship('cQuantum', foreign_keys=[quanID], lazy='joined')
```

In my app I do following:

```
try:
    session = saSession()
    trans = session.query(cTransfer).filter(#some expression).first()
    trans.finished = value
    trans.quantityTransferred = trans.quantityActual = value2
    trans.quanObj.quantityTransferred = trans.quanObj.quantityActual = value2
    trans.quanObj.received = value
    session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    session.rollback()
finally:
    session.close()
```

In 99% of cases everything works OK.

But sometimes only quantityTransferred columns in both cQuantum and cTransfer are updated and the rest of them (quantityActual, finished and received) remain None (NULL in the database, default value). 
Both value and value2 are not None.

Particularly confusing for me is how it is possible that statement

```
obj.col = obj2.col2 = value
```

both objects bound to single session, when committed, produce different results in the database?

Sorry for the longish question. Didn't know how to explain it in less lines. :)

Comment: You don't happen to have multiple workers doing this at the same time? What is the source of value2? What is your session configuration?

Comment: No, there is not multiple workers. Both value and value2 are actually also attributes from an SQLAlchemy object that was populated beforehand in another session which was closed before snippet above.
I can't guarantee that "value" (datetime) was populated (it should have, datetime is present in corresponding database record) but "value2" (float)  certainly was populated because it was assigned to quantityTransferred columns.

Comment: Model objects that have lost their session may have attributes that have not yet loaded their value, iirc, though that does not explain why the other receives a value and the other doesn't

Comment: What happens if you move the assignments to separate?

Comment: That's what I'm gonna try.
I will first store that two values from detached object in two separate variables and then assign each column from those variables 1 assignment - 1 line and hope that that does it.
Still, strange behavior ...

Comment: that `x.y = z.y = a.b` construct produces an attribue load followed by `DUP_TOP` followed by attribute stores, which should not do anything like this, but...

Comment: Are you by happenstance using MySQL for this, or if not, is it possible your database is configured to autocommit.

Comment: The DBMS is MS SQL server 2008. About autocommit I don't know I suppose most of the settings are set to default values.
I've changed the program as indicated above and it worked but that proves nothing since the most of the time previous code worked as well.

Comment: I've checked this autocommit a bit.
SQL server is by default in autommit mode UNTIL transaction begins. Within transaction autocommit is OFF and switched back to ON only after transaction ends with either commit or rollback.
SQLAlchemy has its own autocommit feature which is turned OFF in my case. So this shouldn't be a problem.